# Issue with alignment of horizontal labels in a bar chart

Tags: html, css, highcharts

Having an issue with an app that has huge dependencies on Highcharts+Highstocks. The issue is that the labels for simple bar charts aren't tucked neatly under the bars but instead are skewed to the left way too much. I have too many theories as to why it happens to even mention but if you look at the image I attached you'll see right away (also it's noted in the image).
I've done quite a bit of research and experimentation on this and --- I saw some promise on the API side of things - to really muscle those labels around looks like it might be embedded in the Highcharts js codebase, to which access & forcing overrides is a little bit tricky in the way we implemented Highcharts + Highstocks.

Has anyone encountered this before? If so would you mind a comment or two as to how you managed to get those labels to align under the bars themselves? In a perfect world I'd have those MMM-YY labels centered right beneath the centerline of the bars.

Thank you in advance for your time and for reading this! Any ideas are appreciated and welcomed!
[This is the issue I'm referring to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWrJD.png)

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/labels):

> HTML labels that can be positioned anywhere in the chart area.

Use CSS to position those labels, either:

```
text-align: center;
```

or

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Depending on how the code is structured. If you post your code I can give a more specific fix.